# jquery .attr() not working on an input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

http://jsfiddle.net/uz79M/ Here's my pretty simple code, can anyone tell me why the hell it wont start working xD I'm missing something silly ain't I? Why does the damn value remain on `="test"`?

**Thanks for reading!**

(P.S.: Did I get my tags right or should I delete/replace some of them?)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uz79M/1/ i have made the change and share it . val will work

Comment: wow the reaction time on this by you guys was amazing xD I'll give everyone +1 once I get to the 15 rep ^_^ Thank you so much everyone!

Comment: I'm at 17 now so did as promised :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to change the value of an input element

```
jQuery('input[name="prop_sc_AttachmentType"]').val(selectvalue);
```

Ex: (I've done some more clean up in the code)

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#AttachmentTypeSelect").change(function () {
        var selectvalue = $(this).val();
        if (selectvalue !== "select") {
            $('input[name="prop_sc_AttachmentType"]').val(selectvalue);
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AMST6/)

Also the use of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) was wrong, it should be

```
$(element).attr(attribute, value)
```

ex

```
$(element).attr('tab-index', 1)
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code is not correct, it should be

> .attr('value', selectValue );

or better

> .val( selectValue );

Answer (score 5):

The attr an prop functions of jquery selector are for the attributes which don't have function for that selector. if you want to check or change the value of an input you should call val() function of selector. change your code to this :

```
jQuery('input[name="prop_sc_AttachmentType"]').val(selectvalue);
```

Answer (score 3):

change:

```
 jQuery('input[name="prop_sc_AttachmentType"]').attr('value="' + selectvalue + '"');
```

to

```
jQuery('input[name="prop_sc_AttachmentType"]').val(selectvalue);
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly your `attr()` syntax is incorrect, it should be `attr('prop', 'value');`, secondly to set a value, you should use `val()` anyway. Try this:

```
jQuery('input[name="prop_sc_AttachmentType"]').val(selectvalue);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uz79M/4/)

Answer (score 3):

attr() change to  val()

```
jQuery('input[name="prop_sc_AttachmentType"]').val(selectvalue);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uz79M/3/

Answer (score 3):

it is

```
.attr( attributeName, value )
```

so it will be

```
jQuery('input[name="prop_sc_AttachmentType"]').attr('value',selectvalue);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `val()` to change it's value:

```
jQuery('input[name="prop_sc_AttachmentType"]').val(selectValue);
```

The attribute property is better used for other attributes like title, name etc.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
    if (selectvalue !== "select") {
        jQuery('input[name="prop_sc_AttachmentType"]').attr('value="' + selectvalue + '"');
    }
```

Use

```
  if (selectvalue !== "select") {
        jQuery('input[name="prop_sc_AttachmentType"]').val( selectvalue);
    }
```

Fair trade !:)

Comment: Wow ... 8 answers before i finished typing :D !

Answer (score 2):

You have to use .val() function,

```
jQuery('input[name="prop_sc_AttachmentType"]').val(selectvalue); //standard
```

Or you can correct your code :

```
jQuery('input[name="prop_sc_AttachmentType"]').attr('value', selectvalue);
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uz79M/7/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can set the value directly with the `.val` methode.

Replace this:

`jQuery('input[name="prop_sc_AttachmentType"]').attr('value="' + selectvalue + '"');`

with

`jQuery('input[name="prop_sc_AttachmentType"]').val(selectvalue);`

Comment: It is good form to add an explanation to an answer when providing code itself. While your code may be correct, unless the OP understands why, it is really giving a man a fish, not teaching them to fish - which is what SO is all about.

Comment: Yes, i would edit my answer after posting, but i see that so many people also gives the true answer.. ;)

Comment: I came across this because it had been flagged as a poor quality answer. It doesn't matter how many other answers there are - your answer is a statement that depicts YOU. If you want to answer, answer it as if there were no other answers at all. At the end of the day, one answer will be accepted. Do the best you can to make it yours :)

Comment: Thank you, i will do it better ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is working code

and here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uz79M/9/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var selectvalue = jQuery("select#AttachmentTypeSelect").val();
    jQuery("select#AttachmentTypeSelect").change(function () {
        alert("d")
        selectvalue = jQuery("select#AttachmentTypeSelect").val();
        alert(selectvalue);
        if (selectvalue !== "select") {
            $('input[name="prop_sc_AttachmentType"]').attr('value', selectvalue);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use following :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var selectvalue = jQuery("select#AttachmentTypeSelect").val();

    jQuery("select#AttachmentTypeSelect").change(function () {
        selectvalue = jQuery("select#AttachmentTypeSelect").val();

        if (selectvalue !== "select") {
        jQuery('input[name="prop_sc_AttachmentType"]').val(selectvalue);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var selectvalue = jQuery("select#AttachmentTypeSelect").val();
        jQuery("select#AttachmentTypeSelect").change(function () {
            alert("d")
            selectvalue = jQuery("select#AttachmentTypeSelect").val();
            alert(selectvalue);
            if (selectvalue !== "select") {
                $('input[name="prop_sc_AttachmentType"]').attr('value', selectvalue);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are not using attr function correctly:

this should be like this

```
$('selector').attr({value:desiredValue});
```

or

```
$('selector').attr('value',desiredValue);
```

But for setting values jQuery provides

```
$('selector').val(desiredValue);
```